# doing addition the result should come as five but its coming as NAN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6, scope

- I am doing addition the result should come as five but its coming as undefined.
- I debugged the code for foo.baz and foo.bar it should come as 3 and 2 respectively.
- buts its coming as undefined.
- can you guys tell me whats the problem.
- so that I can proceed further.
- providing my code snippet below

```or-tag-here
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

foo: {
    bar: 2;
    baz: ++bar; //3
};
//3+2

console.log("foo.baz--->", foo.baz);
console.log("foo.bar--->", foo.bar);

console.log("bar--->", bar);

foo.baz + foo.bar + bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch to foo = {bar: 2, baz: bar++ } (as below), this is more what you're looking for. Also, baz equals 2, not 3, as you are adding bar (which = 1) + 1. If you wanted foo.bar and bar are two different variables.

```
var bar = 1,
    foo = {};

foo = {
    bar: 2,
    baz: ++bar //2
};


console.log("foo.baz--->", foo.baz);
console.log("foo.bar--->", foo.bar);

console.log("bar--->", bar);

console.log(foo.baz + foo.bar + bar); // This will equal 6
```

This will console.log foo.baz = 2, foo.bar = 2, bar = 2

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp here is a lesson on how to use objects in JavaScript. If you're wondering why bar=2, it is because ++ changes the value of the variable bar. You could use bar + 1 if you want to keep it's original value.

Comment: Hey in my code foo.baz is coming as undefined, is it due to : and = symbol?

Comment: @zi zi In your code you have assigned ```foo = {}``` so you ```foo = {
    bar: 2,
    baz: ++bar //2
};``` is about assigning the values to foo.

Comment: @Cal hey in my code I am putting colon after foo, where as in CAL CODE HE IS PUTTING EQUAL TO AFTER FOO. MY CODE --->`foo: {
    bar: 2;
    baz: ++bar; //3
};`